# JSON.stringify seeming to not work as expected

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have the following code;

```js
var rawData = [];
rawData['uid'] = 105;
rawData['auth_customer'] = true;
console.log(rawData);
var postData = JSON.stringify(rawData);
console.log(postData);
```

The first console.log is outputting;

```
[uid: 105, auth_customer: true]
```

But the last console.log is just returning a [].
I need the array turned into a json object. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: To produce a JSON object, you should stringify an object. `var rawData = {}`. Arrays are for ordered lists of values, like `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @Ry- Wow! Talk about such a simple fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define rawData as an Object, not an array. So that you can add or remove additional attributes as key:value pair into it. And to back as an Object you should parse using `JSON.parse` like this.

```js
    var rawData = {};
    rawData['uid'] = 105;
    rawData['auth_customer'] = true;

    console.log(rawData); // Object

    var postData = JSON.stringify(rawData);
    console.log(postData); // String - "{'uid':105,'auth_customer':true}"

    console.log(JSON.parse(postData)); // Object
```